# oracle, MULTI_COLUMN_DATASTORE, doesn't use index for consecutive columns

Tags: oracle, full-text-indexing

i have a table with 2 columns, Name and UniqueName. 
I created Multi_column_datastore:

```
SQL> begin
  2  ctx_ddl.create_preference('my_multi', 'MULTI_COLUMN_DATASTORE');
  3   ctx_ddl.set_attribute('my_multi', 'columns', 'Name,UniqueName');
  4  end;
  5  /
```

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

I created the text index like this:

```
SQL> create index text_index on Supplier(Name) indextype is ctxsys.context parameters('datastore my_multi section group CTXSYS.AUTO_SECTION_GROUP SYNC (ON COMMIT)');
```

Index created.

Now, if i query on UniqueName:

```
SELECT count(1) FROM Supplier WHERE CONTAINS (UniqueName , '10') > 0)
```

I get ORA-20000  (Oracle Text error: DRG-10599: column is not indexed)

oracle picks up the text_index only for Name column. It doesn't pickup the index when i query UniqueName.

I also tried creating two separate text indexes one on Name and one on UniqueName.

When i query on UniqueName, though i dont' get error but i don't get any result.

My requirement is to either query on Name or UniqueName (not both). For both, i want to have text index.

Please let me know how to achieve?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can create index like following :

```
create index text_index on Supplier(Name) indextype is ctxsys.context parameters('datastore my_multi SYNC (ON COMMIT)');
```

following query will work in your case as you created index using column "Name":

```
SELECT count(1) FROM Supplier WHERE CONTAINS (Name, '10') > 0;
```